# render_template HTML renders but variables not evaluated

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build an "enterprise grade" version of a flask app so am using blueprints and a fancy directory structure. I have a "toy" version of this app where everything is in a very flat directory structure with no blueprints and it works.

I have a route program that calcs some variables then passes them to `render_template` to generate html. The html displays in the browser but all of the variables appear to be set to `NONE`.

My app uses blueprints and SQLite3.

I have tried multiple things to isolate the error.

1. Make a textual change to html template to ensure the right template is being picked up. It is.
2. Pass trivial string variable to html template and see if they show up, they don't.
3. View source of rendered html, there is *nothing* where the flask variable names {{ x }} occur in the html template, including the {{ x }} text itself. So it appears the value None has been been used.
4. Test the code leading up to the `render_template`, it works perfectly.

My directory structure is: -

```
\myapp
  app.py
  \app
    __init__.py
    \main
      __init__.py
      routes.py
      ...
    \meta
      __init__.py
      routes.py
      ...
    \templates
      ...
      base.html
      index.html
```

The code in \meta\routes.py (which corresponds to the meta blueprint) works down to and including `entitys = stmt.fetchall()` and is: -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3 as sql
from app.meta import bp
from app import Config

config = Config()
metafile = os.path.join(config.META_DIR, config.META_MS, config.META_DB)

@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    meta = sql.connect(metafile)

    stmt = meta.cursor()
    stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM [meta.Entity]")

    entitys = stmt.fetchall()
    return render_template("index.html", entitys = entitys)
```

In case it is relevant here is \meta\__init__.py: -

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('meta', __name__)
```

The template html is as follows. The base.html is: -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }} - Metapplica</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Metapplica</title>
        {% endif %}
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'w3.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <li>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.html is: -

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Entities</h2>
    <table border = 1>
        <thead>
            <td>Entity</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </thead>

        {% for entity in entitys %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ entity["Name"] }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{url_for("entity_list", entity=entity["EntityId"])}}">List</a>
                    <a href="{{url_for("entity_add", entity=entity["EntityId"])}}">Add</a>
                </td>   
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally the rendered html is this: -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

            <title>Home - Metapplica</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="/index">Home</a>
        </div>
        <hr>




    <h2>Entities </h2>
    <table border = 1>
        <thead>
            <td>Entity</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </thead>


    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

In response to @Tobin's comment I have included the code that (should) be registering the blueprint. I use an application factory.

Here is app\__init__()

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request, current_app
from config import Config

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

#   Register blueprints
    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp, url_prefix='/err')

    from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')

    from app.meta import bp as meta_bp
    app.register_blueprint(meta_bp, url_prefix='/meta')

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app
```

and here is the code that calls it: -

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

I suspect that somehow when Flask renders the html template the passed variables are not available to the "flask engine" which is pointing somewhere else.

Nothing fails and there are no error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `print(entitys)` in your python code before your render to make sure your SQL isn't returning 0 rows. If the variables weren't available you would get an error, but the fact that you are just getting no data makes me think it's empty.

Comment: Already done, as i said the code works perfectly up to and including that statement. Also if i pass a trivial variable like test = "testing123" in the render_template and include {{ test }} in the html template i get the same problem.

Comment: Did you register the blueprint in your `\app\__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Tobin, I believe so but will add the code to my question. I use an application factory approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I wasted a week so started again from scratch and the problem is gone. Cheers